# Connecting Ubuntu home server to internet via laptop

Tags: 12.04, networking, server

I recently got a spare desktop computer from a relative to play around with and since I've been using Ubuntu for a few years I decided to install Ubuntu Server 12.04 to play around with and learn more. However it doesn't have a wireless card, the wireless adapter had a shipping error and will be awhile, and plugging it into the router is not an option.

So I figured I could give it access to the wifi from my laptop(which I switch between Windows and Ubuntu) so I could at least get some things started and set up while I'm waiting for the adapter. However the few guides I can find to do that require a GUI, something lacking on the server version.

Could someone tell me how to set this up via the terminal? I would appreciate it.

Comment: What do you want to do with the server?

Comment: I haven't decided yet. Gonna store some files, maybe set up a Minecraft server. Mostly it's just to learn on for now.

Answer (score 0):

https://superuser.com/questions/437137/how-to-turn-my-linux-netbook-into-wifi-ap/437229#437229

Above link walks you through the process of setting up Ubuntu as a wireless access point through the command line. Should get you started, at least.